# How to stick two views together in the center of parent in constraint layout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

[image]

I have implemented below layout using linear layout , I want to get same result using constraint layout, how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **chain** to configure a group of views that are linked to each other with bi-directional position constraints.

Official docs: [Control linear groups with a chain](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/constraint-layout#constrain-chain)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />
    <!-- With packed the views are packed together  -->
    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add a RelativeLayout or LinearLayout within the ContraintLayout and do the same thing.

Comment: That's the thing I strictly want to use Constraint layout only and no other layouts as per the standards.

Comment: using nested layouts in a ConstraintLayout negates the purpose of such layout in the first place